# Why doesn't haddock generate HTML for some modules in base?

Tags: haskell, haddock

There are some modules in the [base](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base) haddock that don't have documentation links. For example, [GHC/Show.hs](https://github.com/ghc/ghc/blob/ef07010cf4f480d9f595a71cf5b009884522a75e/libraries/base/GHC/Show.hs) has haddock comments, but there is no documentation for the `GHC.Show` module on Hackage. Why not? Is this a bug?

Answer (score 2):

This is apparently intentional. It a result of [this line](https://github.com/ghc/ghc/blob/ef07010cf4f480d9f595a71cf5b009884522a75e/libraries/base/GHC/Show.hs#L4) in GHC/Show.hs:

```
{-# OPTIONS_HADDOCK hide #-}
```

Relevant excerpts from [the haddock documentation](https://www.haskell.org/haddock/doc/html/module-attributes.html):

> Certain attributes may be specified for each module which affects the way that Haddock generates documentation for that module. Attributes are specified in a comma-separated list in an `{-# OPTIONS_HADDOCK ... #-}` pragma at the top of the module, either before or after the module description.
>
> [...]
>
> The following attributes are currently understood by Haddock:
>
> - hide
>
>   > Omit this module from the generated documentation, but nevertheless propagate definitions and documentation from within this module to modules that re-export those definitions.
>
> [...]

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't get at *why*. It's pretty annoying.